# Unable to properly add a namespace using XSLT

Tags: xslt, bpel

I am having one problem.

Below XML is getting generated using a Oracle BPEL Process

```
 <gdspCreateVpnNumberList xmlns:ws="http://ws.abc.com/" xmlns="http://ws.abc.com/">
                <ws:numberListName>SampleList105</ws:numberListName>
                <ws:numberListDesc>Desc</ws:numberListDesc>
                <ws:selectedCustomerId>200</ws:selectedCustomerId>
                <ws:numbersList>
                    <ws:number>21</ws:number>
                </ws:numbersList>
            </gdspCreateVpnNumberList>
```

I have applied below xslt to reach above desired input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:ws="http://ws.abc.com/"> 
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="ws:{local-name(.)}"
       namespace="http://ws.abc.com/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, I am unable to generate the actual request which I require:

```
<ws:gdspCreateVpnNumberList xmlns:ws="http://ws.abc.com/">
    <numberListName>SampleList105</ws:numberListName>
    <numberListDesc>Desc</ws:numberListDesc>
    <selectedCustomerId>200</ws:selectedCustomerId>
    <numbersList>
    <number>21</ws:number>
   </numbersList>
</ws:gdspCreateVpnNumberList>
```

Output:

```
        <gdspCreateVpnNumberListResponse xmlns:msgns="http://ws.abc.com/" xmlns="http://ws.abc.com/">
            <return xmlns="">
                <returnCode>
                    <majorReturnCode>100</majorReturnCode>
                    <minorReturnCode>7042</minorReturnCode>
                </returnCode>
            </return>
        </gdspCreateVpnNumberListResponse>
```

Really appreciate your help on this...

Regards,
Ankit

Comment: As of output since it is going to another system so the request is failing due to validation..

Comment: OK, but are you able to see what your current output, maybe by debug logging?

Comment: yes I can see that the system returns error code saying validation error. Problem is in the desired request I have a namespace with a prefix attached to element. I want to replicate this thing since from BPEL process it attaches default namespaces. I have removed those using above xslt but I am unable to get the desired request. Hope this may help you

Comment: Your wanted output is not well-formed. There are namespace prefixes on the end tags, but not on the start tags. Can you update the data to either remove the prefixes from the end tags or add them to the start tags?

Comment: will the above help you DevNull

Comment: No, it's still not clear what you want for output. Updating the output example in your question would be the most helpful.

Comment: Ok below is the output I am getting

Comment: DevNull above is the output I am getting from another system which means the request is failing due to validation. Desired request which i mentioned I need that to be replicated to be able to successfully send the request to another system

Answer (score 0):

Your requested output seems very odd with all elements except the first being in no-namespace, but this generates:

result:

```
<ws:gdspCreateVpnNumberList xmlns:ws="http://ws.abc.com/">
   <numberListName>SampleList105</numberListName>
   <numberListDesc>Desc</numberListDesc>
   <selectedCustomerId>200</selectedCustomerId>
   <numbersList>
      <number>21</number>
   </numbersList>
</ws:gdspCreateVpnNumberList>
```

xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:ws="http://ws.abc.com/"> 
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
 <xsl:element name="ws:{local-name(.)}"
          namespace="http://ws.abc.com/">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks David for your solution but its still not working for me. Can you tell me whether you applied this directly on XML ? In my case it is Oracle BPEL Process which is generating this request so on applying this xsl I am getting a different Request as mentioned below:

Comment: <gdspCreateVpnNumberList xmlns:ws="http://ws.abc.com/" xmlns="http://ws.abc.com.com/">
    <numberListName xmlns="">SampleList105</numberListName>
    <numberListDesc xmlns="">Desc</numberListDesc>
    <selectedCustomerId xmlns="">200</selectedCustomerId>
    <numbersList xmlns="">
     <number>21</number>
    </numbersList>
   </gdspCreateVpnNumberList>

Comment: Your output has xmlns="ws.abc.com.com/" on the top level, the stylesheet you posted nor the one I put in my reply will do that if you want the unprefixed elements to be in no-namespace as in your requested output then the version with xmlns="" is equivalent. If in fact you want the unprefixed elements to be in the namespace and just don't want xmlns="" then add namespace="http://ws.abc.com/" to the second xsl:element in my post.